# How to switch between windows within same group?

Tags: 16.04, application-switcher

If I run several applications of the same name like two terminals or Remmina remote desktop, I am unable to switch between them with Alt-Tab normally anymore: similar windows are grouped within one icon and when I reach it with Alt-Tab, then random window shown. If I wait at this icon holding Alt, it starts to blink grouped windows very fast.

I would like to either disable this "feature", or learn how to handle this situation to switch to desired window.

Comment: If you wait just a moment (with ALT only) the multiple windows will expand. Then tap TAB until it selects the desired window. There's rewally nothing more to it.

Comment: When I waiting with Alt windows do expand, but they flicker if I do nothing.

Comment: You didn't understand. The way to use it proficiently is pressing ALT first and while keeping it pressed also press TAB one by one... When you reach the desired grouped Windows keep pressing **ALT only** and wait for the expansion (if you keeping pressing both then it will flicker, obviously).

Comment: What I think Dims missed is that you first need to wait until the box for the grouped windows shows up, then you need to press the **down arrow** while holding **alt**. Then **left** and **right arrow** selects between the grouped windows. It is not very intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> navigates through the windows - you knew this.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) navigates through grouped windows.

Alt+Esc is working to tab through everything

Comment: on some european keyboards the key is " \ " and not " ` ". In any case, it's the key above tab.